# io.Reader の終端判定方法

Tags: go

io.Reader インタフェースの

```go
func Read(p []byte) (n int, err error)
```

で、全てを読みつくしたかどうかを判定する方法で迷っています。
思いつく限りでは以下の３つなのですが、優劣はありますでしょうか。

**１．戻り値 `n` がゼロだったら「終わり」**

```go
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    r := bytes.NewBuffer([]byte{1, 2, 3})
    b := make([]byte, 2)

    for {
        n, err := r.Read(b)

        if n == 0 {
            break
        }

        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        fmt.Println(b[:n])
    }
}
```

**Ｂ．戻り値 `err` が `io.EOF` だったら「終わり」**

```go
    for {
        n, err := r.Read(b)

        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            panic(err)
        }

        fmt.Println(b[:n])
    }
```

**Ｃ．戻り値 `n` が 用意したバッファサイズより小さかったら「終わり」**

```
    for {
        n, err := r.Read(b)

        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        fmt.Println(b[:n])

        if n < len(b) {
            break
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/bytes/buffer.go#L298 を眺めてみますと、この条件(r, b)では C の場合、2 回 read して終了となるので、ほんの少しは有利かな、とは思います。それから、Read() のソースコードには `if len(p) == 0 ...` という部分があります。`b := make([]byte, 0)` とした場合(現実的にその様なコードは書かないとは思いますが)、B と C では無限ループになります。

Comment: @metropolis 無限ループになる点、おっしゃる通りです。ありがとうございます。リンク先の実装の件、バッファが空の場合なのでerrはnilではなくEOFを返すほうがよいのでは、とは思いました（きっと何か理由があるのだと思いますが）。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`io.Reader`のドキュメント](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader)には、

> It returns the number of bytes read (0 <= n <= len(p)) and any error encountered.

とあるので、`n==0`だけで判定すると誤りと思います。
また、上記説明の後に、

> If some data is available but not len(p) bytes, Read conventionally returns what is available instead of waiting for more.

ともあるので、`n < len(p)`で判定するのも誤りと思います。

なので、質問文にある「B. 戻り値`err`が`io.EOF`だったら『終わり』」と判定するのが
正しいかと思います。

＃ただし、`err`が`io.EOF`でも、`n>0`の場合があると記載されているので、`n==0`との複合条件で判断した方がよいと思います。

Comment: [ioのcopyBufferの実装](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/io/io.go#L403)を見ると、まずn>0を判定した後、次にnの値に関わらずerrの有無を判定しているようでしたので、おっしゃる通りnとerrの両方を見る必要があるようです。ありがとうございます。